# Reactjs: How to set "temp" value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my project, there is an input field to add tags.
[image]

Here my requirement is when I click on the "X" button value should delete and when I click on the tag the value will display on the input field.

But when I click on the "X" button, the value is showing in the input field, I added the "temp" flag to avoid it, but it doesn't work as expected.

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    items: [],
    value: "",
    error: null,
    temp: true
  };

  handleKeyDown = evt => {
    if (["Enter", "Tab", ","].includes(evt.key)) {
      evt.preventDefault();

      var value = this.state.value.trim();

      if (value && this.isValid(value)) {
        this.setState({
          items: [...this.state.items, this.state.value],
          value: ""
        });
      }
    }
  };

  handleChange = evt => {
    this.setState({
      value: evt.target.value,
      error: null
    });
  };

  handleDelete = item => {
    console.log("delete")
    this.setState({
      items: this.state.items.filter(i => i !== item),
      temp: true,
    });
    console.log("temp in delete", this.state.temp)
  };
  
  handleItemEdit = item =>{
    console.log("temp in edit", this.state.temp)
    if (this.state.temp==true){
      this.setState({
        temp: false
        
      });
    }else{
      console.log("1")
      const result = this.state.items.filter(values=>values!==item)
      this.setState({
        value: item,
        error: null,
        items: result
      });
    }
  }

  handlePaste = evt => {
    evt.preventDefault();

    var paste = evt.clipboardData.getData("text");
    var emails = paste.match(/[\w\d\.-]+@[\w\d\.-]+\.[\w\d\.-]+/g);

    if (emails) {
      var toBeAdded = emails.filter(email => !this.isInList(email));

      this.setState({
        items: [...this.state.items, ...toBeAdded]
      });
    }
  };

  isValid(email) {
    let error = null;

    if (this.isInList(email)) {
      error = `${email} has already been added.`;
    }

    if (!this.isEmail(email)) {
      error = `${email} is not a valid email address.`;
    }

    if (error) {
      this.setState({ error });

      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }

  isInList(email) {
    return this.state.items.includes(email);
  }

  isEmail(email) {
    return /[\w\d\.-]+@[\w\d\.-]+\.[\w\d\.-]+/.test(email);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {this.state.items.map(item => (
          <div className="tag-item" key={item} onClick={() => this.handleItemEdit(item)}>
            {item}
            <button
              type="button"
              className="button"
              onClick={() => this.handleDelete(item)}
            >
              &times;
            </button>
          </div>
        ))}

        <input
          ref={this.state.items}
          className={"input " + (this.state.error && " has-error")}
          value={this.state.value}
          placeholder="Type or paste email addresses and press `Enter`..."
          onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          onPaste={this.handlePaste}
        />

        {this.state.error && <p className="error">{this.state.error}</p>}
      </>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Please give me some suggestions to overcome this problem.

Comment: You seem to be overcomplicating the problem, a better problem to solve is preventing the click that triggers `handleDelete()` from also triggering `handleItemEdit()` on the parent element (E.g. Using `event.stopPropagation()`)

Comment: Two suggestions: 1. Unless this is legacy code, you should not be writing class-based JS code in 2022  2. Break your state up or at the very least, remember to spread the old state first.